# System task or function '$value$plusarg' is not defined -> Warning : Verilog

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I am trying to learn how to use **$value$plusarg**. I have picked up the following code from somewhere.

```
module test;
integer i, r;

initial begin
  r = $value$plusarg("myint=%d", i);
  $display("Value is %0d", i);
end

endmodule
```

When I tried to run it, I am getting the warning as:

```
System task or function '$value$plusarg' is not defined.
```

I have used Modelsim. The commands I have used are as follows:

```
vlog test_genvar.v +define+myint="22"
vsim work.test
run -all
```

I am not sure if the problem is with the code or the commands I have used. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very silly mistake. The system task name is `$value$plusargs` and not `$value$plusarg` (missing 's'..!!!).

Moreover, you may use `$test$plusargs` to detect/test whether the given switch is available at run-time or not. Like as follows:

```
if($test$plusargs("myint"))
begin
$value$plusargs("myint=%d",i);
end
```

One more thing, I am using VCS, and to provide these kind of switches, I use simply "./simv +myint=5" (of course simv is my compiled-executable file). So, no need of `+define+myint=5`, directly `+myint=5` should work.

Also, these are run-time switches and not compile time. So, I think they should be with `vsim` command and not `vlog`, but I am not sure about this. Not  big deal, I guess.

Your code is available [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Emi) at EDAPlayground, simulated with VCS. Just for reference.

Comment: It is indeed run-time switch. If I use with the vlog, I am getting output as **x**. Thanks for that :)

Comment: Also can I know when do we use **+define**?

Comment: `+define` is likely to be used to define a macro condition. For example, you have a code with `ifdef ABC`, then `+define+ABC` will define `ABC` macro.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a copy of the [1800-2012 LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html)? If you did, you would see that you have misspelled something.

Comment: I should have looked at the standard. Learned a lesson :)